# How to build a master formula sheet, that is importrange(d) into identically structured workbooks that directly use the imported sheet's formuals

Tags: google-sheets-api, google-workspace

I do operations for restaurants and I have a fairly robust set of google sheets that communicate with one another to work in tandem.

One thing I have is a lot of recipes for different dishes, seasonings, etc.  I have made updates to this recipe workbook, that contains much more info than just the recipes, so making updates is a tedious process given I have to basically rewrite the recipes and accompanying information from the updated template.

My goal is to have the recipe workbook, refernce a master formula sheet that I will import into the recipe workbook.  The recipes will then refernce a cell within the import sheet that contains the desired forumla. This will make updating the recipes much much easier.

My issue is that importrange wont inmport formulas, only answers.

I have the following workbooks below that hopefully helps explain the above.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1io0JNqV6_ZiNwE-pZBeRkTk1YIdq-ZMvofybSWzJ7NU/edit?usp=sharing

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1soS1OxckAv4uK1qkMPJZ8_GPEc8KwQlkwrHqzUlbB7I/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Provide data in the question so we can see what you mean - links to external sheets are not likely to be clicked on for many reasons like the possibility of catching a virus.